# Merge two base64 urls and generate one PDF

Tags: html, angular, web, client-side

I have one PDF generated by jsPDF. I also have one other PDF as base64. I need to merge these two PDFs and download them as one PDF. 
I have tried canvas, PDF merger, easy pdf merge, and so many other libraries.